# SQL-запрос для выборки последних записей

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `messages`, имеющая следующий вид : `_id (prim key), author, client, time, content.`

Пусть она имеет такие значения :

```
 _id | author | client | time  | content
--------------------------------------
   1 |  user  |  you   | 21:52 | hi   
   2 |  user  |  you   | 20:43 | wassup   
   3 |  user2 |  you   | 17:45 | привет   
   4 |  user2 |  you   | 18:20 | :(
```

Из этой таблицы нужно получить по ОДНОМУ (последнему) сообщению от каждого author'a, где `client = you`.

Т.е. с помощью запроса необходимо вернуть сообщения с id 1 и 4 (`hi` и `:(`). Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Действительно здесь ошибка:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `client` = 'you'
GROUP BY `author`
ORDER BY `time` DESC;
```

Сортировка происходит после групировки, Вам необходим такой запрос:

```
SELECT `message`.*
FROM `message`
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT max(`time`) AS `maxTime`, `author`
    FROM `message`
    GROUP BY `author`
) AS `max`
    ON (`max`.`author` = `message`.`author` // При возможности связать по ID
        AND `max`.`maxTime` = `message`.`time`
        AND `client` = 'you'
    )
ORDER BY `time` DESC;
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, только ORDER BY должен быть после GROUP BY

Comment: @Schepalin на моём примере в sqlfiddle он выдаст сообщения с id 1 и 3, это разве верно?

Comment: @Schepalin Во первых у вас могут возникнуть серьезные проблемы при смене версии MySQL потому как в group by должны быть указаны все колонки, которые присутствуют в списке выборки без групповых функций (а тут у нас вообще *). Во вторых ORDER BY работает уже _после_ group by и если вдруг на какой то БД такой запрос выдает нужный результат - то это вопрос везения, а не правильного запроса. такой group by в MySQL выдаст первую попавшуюся строку а не с максимальной датой

Comment: В вашем подзапросе после `INNER JOIN` будет ошибка при других данных в БД - если там будет `client` не `you` и именно у него будет max(time), то будет получено другое сообщение. Необходимо подзапрос дополнить еще и кортежем `client`.

Answer (score 6):

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/037b15/6)

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM test t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT author, client, max(time) as mtime
                         FROM test
                         WHERE client = 'you'
                         GROUP BY author, client) t2
     ON t1.author = t2.author AND t1.client = t2.client AND t1.time = t2.mtime
```

Comment: @Mike не подскажете, в MySQL есть аналог `keen (dense_rank first order by ...)` как в Oracle? Можно было бы красивее сделать решение.

Comment: В MySQL никаких оконных функций нет. кумулятивные результаты можно получать только с помощью переменных и "ручной группировки". что то типа `select * from (
select *,@num:=if(author=@grp, @num+1, 0) N,@grp:=author
  from test, (select @grp:='', @num:=0) A
 order by author, time
) A where N=0` выйдет