# MSSQL - как поправить запрос?

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте, помогите с запросом пожалуйста:

```
select * from sc84 as nom   
join sc319 as p   
on p.PARENTEXT = nom.id   
join sc219 as pt   
on p.sp327 = pt.id  
join _1SCONST as c  
on c.objid=p.id
```

В результате у меня примерно такая таблица

```
Чайник / закупочная / 08-08-2016:13-40 / 100 /   
Чайник / закупочная / 08-08-2016:14-40 / 150 /   
Чайник / закупочная / 08-09-2016:13-40 / 190 /   
Чайник / оптовая / 08-09-2016:18-40 / 210 /   
Чайник / оптовая / 08-10-2016:13-40 / 290 /
```

То есть товары, типы цены даты и их значения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как           получить последнюю(актуальную цену для каждого типа цены и каждого товара)     пробывал варианты с группировкой но явно не хватает скила.

- nom.id - PK товаров
- pt.id - PK типов цен
- p.id - PK цен
- p.parentext - владелец цены
- p.sp327 - внешний ключ на тип цены
- колонка с датой так и называется date

Comment: посмотреть тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/256169/ "Приложение 2 – OVER и аналитические функции" , должно помочь

Comment: да вот что то не помогло...

Comment: Вот вчера например вопрос был http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558397/sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9  очень похоже. И указывайте всегда какой диалект SQL (БД) используется, решения то разные могут быть ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по комментариям у вас видимо MS-SQL, какая версия и какие оконные функции она поддерживает к сожалению вы в вопросе не указали. Будем считать, что функция row_number() у вас есть. В таком случае из любого запроса можно выбрать максимальные строки примерно таким образом:

```
 select * from (
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by nom.id,pt.id order by c.date desc) NUM
     from sc84 as nom   
     join sc319 as p   
       on p.PARENTEXT = nom.id   
     join sc219 as pt   
       on p.sp327 = pt.id  
     join _1SCONST as c  
       on c.objid=p.id
  ) A
  where NUM=1
```

В `partiton by` предложения OVER надо указать колонки в разрезе которых нам нужны максимумы и задать правильный порядок сортировки. row_number при это пронумерует записи и те, что окажутся с номерами 1 и будут нужные нам.

Answer (score 0):

Привет, 
посмотрите такой вариант:

```
select nom.id, pt.id, p.id, p.parenttext,p.sp327,p.date 
from sc84 as nom   
    join 
    (
        select pt.id, p.id, p.parenttext,p.sp327,p.date  
        from sc319 p1 
            outer apply (select max(p2.date) maxdate from sc319 p2 where p2.id = p1.id ) as maxdate
        where p.date = maxdate
    ) as p
        on p.PARENTEXT = nom.id   
    join sc219 as pt   
        on p.sp327 = pt.id  
    join _1SCONST as c  
        on c.objid=p.id
```

**Обновление**

аналогично можно сделать запрос и с _1SCONST, в outer apply выбираете максимальную дату для objid, затем забираете значение цены из _1SCONST для конкретного objid и его максимальной даты

```
select nom.id, pt.id, p.id, p.parenttext,p.sp327,с.date, c.value
from sc84 as nom   
    join sc319 p 
        on p.PARENTEXT = nom.id   
    join sc219 as pt   
        on p.sp327 = pt.id  

join 
    (
        select c1.objid, c1.VALUE /* сюда выбираете цену */
        from _1SCONST c1 
            outer apply (select max(c2.date) maxdate from _1SCONST c2 where c2.objid = c1.objid ) as maxdate
        where c.date = maxdate
    ) as с
    --join _1SCONST as c  
        on c.objid=p.id
```

Comment: Дмитрий спасибо за ваш ответ, но поля с датой у меня есть только в таблице _1SCONST, я привел структуру таблиц на англоязычной версии портала  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112868/write-sql-server-query если вам будет не затруднительно посмотрите пожалуйста