# Как вывести столбец, соответствующий значению агрегатной функции?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

К примеру, есть таблица с покупателями и есть таблица с заказами. В запросе я джойню эти таблицы по id покупателя, но вывожу в итоге лишь список покупателей со сводными данными по заказам. Так вот, мне нужно, чтобы в результаты запроса попал заказ с минимальной суммой. Саму минимальную сумму я могу вывести при помощи функции min(столбец_с_суммой), но как вывести, например, другое поле из таблицы с заказами, соответствующее минимальной сумме? Я, конечно, могу сделать что то типа

```
SELECT 
  п.покупатель
  , (SELECT Другое_поле FROM заказы зак WHERE зак.столбец_с_суммой = min(п.покупатель) AND зак.покупательИД = п.покупательИД)
FROM покупатели п
JOIN заказы з ON з.покупательИД = п.покупательИД
GROUP BY п.покупатель
```

но тут получается запрос данных, которые уже выбраны в основном запросе. Чутье подсказывает мне, что здесь можно воспользоваться оконными выражениями, но я никогда с ними не работал, готовых примеров найти не смог и разобраться пока не могу.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Чутье подсказывает мне, что здесь можно воспользоваться оконными
>   выражениями

Верно оно вам подсказывает.

Здесь можно воспользоваться нумерующей функцией `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH заказы_покупателя AS (
    SELECT
        з.покупательИД,
        з.столбец_с_суммой,
        з.Другое_поле,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY з.покупательИД
            ORDER BY з.столбец_с_суммой)
    FROM заказы з
)
SELECT п.покупатель, зп.столбец_с_суммой, зп.Другое_поле
FROM покупатели п
    JOIN заказы_покупателя зп ON зп.покупательИД = п.покупательИД AND зп.RN = 1;
```

При помощи `PARTITION BY` задаём окно (нумеруем строки `заказы з` в пределах одинаковых `з.покупательИД`). При помощи `ORDER BY` задаём порядок нумерации (по увеличению `з.столбец_с_суммой`). В `JOIN` указываем дополнительное условие `зп.RN = 1`, что отфильтрует только одну строку для каждого `зп.покупательИД` (с минимальным значением `столбец_с_суммой`).

Если у одного покупателя может быть несколько заказов с одной и той же минимальной суммой и нужно выбрать из них *какой-то конкретный*, то в `ORDER BY` нужно добавить дополнительное поле, например дату заказа или его ИД `ORDER BY з.столбец_с_суммой, з.заказИД`.

Если у одного покупателя может быть несколько заказов с одной и той же минимальной суммой и нужно выбрать их *все*, то вместо `ROW_NUMBER()` нужно использовать `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY з.покупательИД ORDER BY з.столбец_с_суммой)`.