# Запрос в БД с игнорированием полей в Group By (MSSQL 2008)

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Доброго времени суток.
Возникла сложность с составлением запроса к БД:

Для объекта с ID 1 нужно выделить все вложения (Attachment), их создателя и дату из второй таблицы. В данном случае вложения будут file.txt и bar.png.

Связать обе таблицы можно лишь по названию вложения; во второй таблице оно содержится в info. Также у второй таблицы при добавлении файла в поле [info] попадает дата, поэтому строки 0 и 5 - разные.

Сложность в выделении из второй таблицы: file.txt был добавлен 2 раза и нужно выделить именно последнюю по дате строку из истории (с ID = 5).

Примерный макет имеющихся таблиц:

**Table Attachment:**

```
| ID | name     | ObjID | type |
| 0  | file.txt |   1   |  0   |
| 1  | foo.jpg  |   2   |  0   |
| 2  | bar.png  |   1   |  0   |
```

**Table History:**

```
| ID | date | creator |     info                |   ObjID  |
| 0  | 0001 |   123   | added file.txt (0001)   |    1     |
| 1  | 0002 |   123   | added bar.png (0002)    |    1     |
| 2  | 0015 |   777   | some action for prt1    |    1     |
| 3  | 0017 |   777   | some action for prt2    |    2     |
| 4  | 0019 |   123   | removed file.txt (0019) |    1     |
| 5  | 0023 |   777   | added file.txt (0023)   |    1     |
```

Результат должен быть таким:

```
| AttachmentId |    name    | ObjID | type | date | creator | 
|      0       |   file.txt |   1   |  0   | 0023 |   777   |
|      2       |   bar.png  |   1   |  0   | 0002 |   123   |
```

Я пытался использовать Max(date), но тогда возникает проблема с группировкой: ведь строки 0 и 5 в истории отличаются во многих полях.
Как составить к этому запрос?

Заранее спасибо.

P.S. MSSQL 2008.

Comment: А как вы первые 2 таблицы склеили, по like что ли имя файла искали ? Можете привести запрос до которого вы уже дошли, проще его доделать, чем писать с 0

Comment: А что бы записи для максимального поля взять можно сделать например `row_number() over (partition by AttachmentId order by date desc) RN` и в внешнем запросе отобрать записи с RN=1

Comment: Собственно вот как тут: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558704/mssql-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81/558797#558797

Comment: @Mike, да, таблицы склеивал по like. Запрос выглядел [примерно так](http://pastebin.com/5i6N6gn7). #{entityId} - переменная, которая отвечает за то, по какому объекту мы ищем вложения. С row_number() еще не пытался, завтра обязательно попробую.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло использование `row_number() over (partition by ...);`

Вот запрос, который выделит из тех двух таблиц то, что нужно:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM 
  (
      SELECT
        Attachment.ID as AttachmentId
        , Attachment.name
        , Attachment.ObjID
        , Attachment.type
        , dbo.ToMS(History.date)
        , History.creator
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY
           SUBSTRING(History.info,6,LEN(History.info)-6-7)
           ORDER BY
             History.date DESC
        ) ROW_NUMBER
      FROM
         Attachment
         LEFT OUTER JOIN History 
           ON History.ObjID = Attachment.ObjID AND History.info LIKE ('%added ' + Attachment.name + '%')
      WHERE
         Attachment.ObjID = #{entityId}
  ) as SubQuery
WHERE
  SubQuery.ROW_NUMBER = 1
ORDER BY
  SubQuery.creationDate
```

Таблицы склеиваются по LIKE - названию файла. В PARTITION BY указан Substring который обрежет из History.info ровно название файла, там всегда фиксированное количество символов справа и слева от названия. Также для удобства весь запрос дополнительно отсортирован по дате в конце.