# SQL запрос с группировкой

Tags: sql-server

Возможно, вопрос будет выглядеть как "сделайте за меня", тем не менее, это не так. Прошу рассказать куда копать. Однако, если у кого есть возможность написать сам запрос и прокоментить его — вы меня осчастливите.
Есть таблица:

```
TABLE (
    event_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    base_event_id BIGINT REFERENCES base_events (id) NOT NULL,
    person_id BIGINT REFERENCES persons (id) NOT NULL,
    event_date DATETIME NOT NULL
)
```

Задача состоит в том, чтобы собрать `event_id`, у которых одинаковые `base_event_id` и `person_id`, имеющие `MAX( event_date )`. Грубо говоря, последний раз ,когда конкретный человек был на определённом мероприятии.
В голове только история с временными таблицами и кучей подзапросов на саму таблицу. Уверен, что есть элегантное решение через группировку, или ещё что-то крутое.
Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: `row_number() over(partition by base_event_id, person_id order by event_date desc) RN` пронумерует вам строки так, что первыми будут именно с максимальной датой в нужном разрезе. Останется завернуть это во внешний запрос и отобрать их (по where RN=1)

Comment: В общем как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/558797/194569

Comment: @Mike, огромное спасибо!