# Агрегирующие функции в OVER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Хочу разобраться, как искать максимальную или минимальную дату в подгруппах по другому столбцу таблицы.

Например, есть таблица `DF`, в которой 3 колонки:
(*Клиент, номер анкеты, и дата заведения анкеты*)

| IDCLIENT | IDBLANK | DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-03-02 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-03-03 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-03-02 |
| 2 | 5 | 2021-03-03 |
| 2 | 6 | 2021-03-04 |
| 3 | 7 | 2021-03-03 |
| 3 | 8 | 2021-03-04 |
| 3 | 9 | 2021-03-05 |

> Нужно найти минимальную дату по каждому клиенту

Исходя из статей найденных в интернете, для этого нужно использовать `OVER PARTITION BY`. Мой запрос выглядит так :

```
select min(dt) over (partition by idclient)
from df
```

Запрос вернул то, что я хотел:

| IDCLIENT | IDBLANK | DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-03-01 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-03-02 |
| 2 | 5 | 2021-03-02 |
| 2 | 6 | 2021-03-02 |
| 3 | 7 | 2021-03-03 |
| 3 | 8 | 2021-03-03 |
| 3 | 9 | 2021-03-03 |

> Теперь, цель получить первую (по дате) анкету по клиенту.

Запрос:

```
select
  idblank
 ,idclient
 ,dt
from df
where dt in ( -- по минимальной дате пытаюсь вытянуть номер клиента и анкету
  select 
    min(dt) over (partition by idclient)
  from df)
```

Но результат:

| IDCLIENT | IDBLANK | DT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-03-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-03-02 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-03-03 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-03-02 |
| 2 | 5 | 2021-03-03 |
| 3 | 7 | 2021-03-03 |

Не понятно, почему такой вывод, в подзапросе *уникальных* дат было 3, "в моем понимании", 3 анкеты должен вернуть запрос. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ed088291ff264faa0cdb81ecbfd21963)

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: первая по дате анкета по клиенту, это `row_number() over(partition by idclient order by DT) RN` и потом отобрать записи с RN=1. Типа такого https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/558797/194569

Comment: @Mike, Спасибо ! получилось. Как я понял, для получения минимальной или максимальной даты используются не `min` и `max` а сортировка `order by` а для максимальной даты нужно добавить `desk`

Comment: Плюс за образцовое оформлрние вопроса с данными и фидлом!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Теперь, цель получить первую (по дате) анкету по клиенту.

Функция так и называется [FIRST](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions065.htm#SQLRF00641) - *получить первую(е)*.

Ни подзапрос, ни тем более аналитические функции в нём, тут не нужны.
Таким запросом будет получен желаемый результат ([db<>fiddlle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=810ddca9b5f42f779f9fc3be956fd336)):

```
select idclient, 
    min (idblank) keep (dense_rank first order by dt asc) idblank, 
    min (dt)      keep (dense_rank first order by dt asc) dt
from df
group by idclient;

  IDCLIENT    IDBLANK DT                 
---------- ---------- -------------------
         1          1 2021-03-01 12:00:00
         2          4 2021-03-02 12:00:00
         3          7 2021-03-03 12:00:00
```

---

***Важное замечание***: Загоковок вопроса: *Агрегирующие функции в OVER*, показывает, что нет ещё полного понимания главного отличия агрегатных от аналитических функций. Они в принципе не могут быть "одна в другой" или "вместе", поэтому коротко для понимания:

- Агрегатные функции (*aggregate function*) применяются к набору (или группе) данных и возвращают по ним ***одну строку** с результирующим значением*.
- Аналитические функции (*analytic function*) начинающиеся с клаузы `OVER`,  применяются также к набору (или группе) данных, но возвращают по ним *результирующее значение для **каждой строки*** набора (или группы) данных.

Comment: для несведующих несколько странные отсылки к `over`, который не употребляется в приведенном запросе

Comment: @teran OVER в заголовке вопроса, я к ней не отсылаю. Вы скорее всего не совсем поняли, что хотел донести в эпилоге. Прямо процитируйте фразу, которая кажется "сомнительной", и  пояснените, как вы её поняли.

Comment: Спасибо ! не знал о таком подходе.

Comment: @Akalit Рад был помочь! Вам понятен эпилог в ответе, он коротко раскрывает причину, по которой вам не удалось решить самостоятельно.