# Оконные функции в R

Tags: r

Есть таблица

```
DF <- tibble(
  CLIENT = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  N_DOG = c('N1','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8','N9'),
  DT = as.Date(c('01.06.2021','12.07.2021','04.05.2021',
                 '03.08.2021','21.07.2021','04.01.2022',
                 '07.04.2021','09.11.2021','08.12.2021'), format = '%d.%m.%Y'),
  RANK = c(1,1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3)
)
```

| CLIENT | N_DOG | DT | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | N1 | 2021-06-01 | 1 |
| 1 | N2 | 2021-07-12 | 1 |
| 1 | N3 | 2021-05-04 | 2 |
| 2 | N4 | 2021-08-03 | 3 |
| 2 | N5 | 2021-07-21 | 1 |
| 2 | N6 | 2022-01-04 | 1 |
| 3 | N7 | 2021-04-07 | 2 |
| 3 | N8 | 2021-11-09 | 2 |
| 3 | N9 | 2021-12-08 | 3 |

> Нужно по каждому клиенту найти договор по следующим критериям :
>
> 1. Найти договор с минимальным рангом
> 2. Если таких договоров несколько, берём последний

> PS. На выходе должен быть уникальный клиент и 1 договор по условиям выше

Реализация

```
MIN_RANK <- DF %>% 
  select(CLIENT, RANK) %>% 
  group_by(CLIENT) %>% 
  filter(RANK == min(RANK)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct()

MIN_RANK %>% 
  inner_join(DF, by = c('CLIENT','RANK')) %>% 
  select(!c(N_DOG,RANK)) %>% 
  group_by(CLIENT) %>% 
  filter(DT == max(DT)) %>% 
  inner_join(DF, by = c('CLIENT','DT'))
```

Финал

| CLIENT | DT | N_DOG | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-12 | N2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2022-01-04 | N6 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-11-09 | N8 | 2 |

Как данное действие можно сделать быстрее ? [ может есть уже написанная функция ] 
Подобное на форуме есть для [SQL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1332027/%D0%90%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-over)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  CLIENT = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
  N_DOG = c('N1','N2','N3','N4','N5','N6','N7','N8','N9'),
  DT = as.Date(c('01.06.2021','12.07.2021','04.05.2021',
                 '03.08.2021','21.07.2021','04.01.2022',
                 '07.04.2021','09.11.2021','08.12.2021'), format = '%d.%m.%Y'),
  RANK = c(1,1,2,3,1,1,2,2,3)
)

dt[order(RANK, -DT), .SD[1], keyby = CLIENT]
```